# Wildfly run timeout altough the server is launched

Tags: maven, maven-3, wildfly, maven-plugin, wildfly-10

Here is the configuration I used in order to use test integration in maven  :

```
        [...]
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.Final</version>

            <configuration>
                <jboss-home>${wildfly.home}</jboss-home>
                <modules-path>${wildfly.home}/modules</modules-path>
                <hostname>localhost</hostname>
                <username>XXX</username>
                <password>XXX</password>
                <serverArgs>
                    <serverArg>-b=0.0.0.0</serverArg>
                    <serverArg>-bmanagement=0.0.0.0</serverArg>
                </serverArgs>
                <env>
                    <jboss.server.base.dir>${wildfly.home}/standalone</jboss.server.base.dir>
                    <jboss.host.name>localhost</jboss.host.name>
                    <!--<jboss.socket.binding.port-offset>${wildfly.portoffset}</jboss.socket.binding.port-offset>-->
                </env>
                <javaOpts>
                    <javaOpt>-server</javaOpt>
                    <javaOpt>-Xms8192m</javaOpt>
                    <javaOpt>-Xmx8192m</javaOpt>
                </javaOpts>
                <serverConfig>standalone-full.xml</serverConfig>
                <startupTimeout>480</startupTimeout>
                <timeout>480</timeout>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>wildfly-run</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <name>${app.name}</name>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>wildfly-stop</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>undeploy</goal>
                        <goal>shutdown</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <name>${app.name}</name>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        [...]
```

Everything works and I am able to connect to the admin panel on localhost:9990 port but :

```
Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-
plugin:1.2.0.Final:start (wildfly-run) on project qc_server: The server failed to start: The server did not start within 480 seconds.
```

Is there something I have missed ?

The war is deployed, java args are passed and server args too.

Well everythings works and Wildlfy states war as deployed.

The only suspicious thing is :

```
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.patching.manager: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.patching.manager: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate layer 'base'
```

Comment: Are there any messages after the failure? Like maybe something about not being able to connect.

Comment: yep there is an unable to connect but I don't know how to debug it. And considering that I do connect to the server (administration and deployement) , this is weird.

Comment: The username and password aren't likely required. Have you tried commenting those out?

Answer (score 1):

you asked this question long time ago, but I post my answer for future searches.
you probably change the admin port in your configuration file and you have to set that port in the configuration section of wildfly-maven-plugin. for example :

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <configuration>
    <port>7770</port>
</configuration>
```